# Twillio Access token returns 20101 Invalid Access Token

Tags: swift, twilio

I am using the *Twilio* testing tools to generate an access token that I can use to familiarize myself with the getting started project

`https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift#setup`.

However, whenever I generate one, I get an error when I run the project on the simulator.
This is the error;

> Connection Failed couldn't connect to room arkit. code: 20101 Invalid
>   Access Token.

**Note**: I just started using twilio and so my knowledge is very basic.
I initially thought there is a specific user id one should post in the client identity field here https://www.twilio.com/console/video/runtime/testing-tools.

However, I figured you use any name and it should work. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you generate the access token for the room "arkit"? That's the bit that might block you. You can check out the content of your JWT with https://jwt.io which is useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you change your scheme from the default ARKitExample to the VideoQuickStart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured what the problem was since I was sending the phone number in my code, the `+` in the country code was getting decoded as space. The number that was being sent to the API was therefore wrong and it could never work.

Comment: Should probably be closed under `close`->`should be closed`->`offtopic`->`simple typograhical error`